# 2 Datasets from 1 Subscription make 1 set readonly or apply changes to 1 set (Angular)

Tags: angular, observable, http-get, subscription

Good Morning.

I have a service that takes along time to return its result. Worst still - I have to call it twice.

The returned data forms 2 grids (one editable) which fires other events when changes are made.

If i separate the subscription, changes made to the second array is contained to this dataset

If I subscribe to the service once and create 2 datasets any changes made to the array flows through to both sets.

I suspect the issue is to do with how I subscribe to my service

```
this._CashService.getCash()
  .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
    this.cash = data;
    this.cash2 = data;
});
```

Here is a plunker showing my issue

https://plnkr.co/GwgBD1Mp8XF5oLZoYt4k?p

I don't wont the top grid to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was binding the first grid to the "cash" variable and the second grid to "cash2", these variables referenced the same array ("data" that came from my service). So, when I modified an item of the "cash2" array, the "cash" array was modified as well.

To edit the arrays separately, I needed to make a copy of the original array. To do this for this example, it required

```
this.cash2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```